# What is the fastest way to serialize to ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, serialization, ehcache, bytebuffer

I would like to write serializer for Ehcache of Optional class. I know, that optional member is seriazizable, so I write:

```
@Override
   public ByteBuffer serialize(Optional object) throws SerializerException {

      if( object.isPresent() ) {
         try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(object);
            return ByteBuffer.wrap(baos.toByteArray()); // excess copying
         } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
         }

      }
      else {
         return ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {});
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Optional read(ByteBuffer binary) throws ClassNotFoundException, SerializerException {
      if( binary.array().length > 0 ) {
         try {
            byte[] buf = binary.array();
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            Object object = ois.readObject();
            return Optional.of(object);
         } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
         }
      }
      else {
         return Optional.empty();
      }
   }
```

I confused by commented line, which includes excess copying of data. Can I avoid it and serialize directly with ByteBuffer?

While does Ehcache seriazliers based of ByteBuffer?

Answer (score 0):

`ByteBuffer.wrap()` doesn't actually copy data. As the name implies it wraps the array, so any changes to the original array would also be reflected in the buffer.

Comment: I meant `baos.toByteArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can't do Java serialization on a ByteBuffer. You are doing the same thing as the built-in `PlainJavaSerializer` of Ehcache.

By the way, you could remove a lot of code by doing this:

```
public class OptionalSerializer<T> implements Serializer<Optional<T>> {

  private final PlainJavaSerializer<T> serializer;

  public OptionalSerializer(ClassLoader classLoader) {
      serializer = new PlainJavaSerializer<>(classLoader);
  }

  @Override
  public ByteBuffer serialize(Optional<T> object) throws SerializerException {
    return object.map(serializer::serialize).orElse(ByteBuffer.allocate(0));
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<T> read (ByteBuffer binary) throws ClassNotFoundException, SerializerException {
    if(binary.array().length > 0) {
      return Optional.of(serializer.read(binary));
    }
    return Optional.empty();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Optional<T> object, ByteBuffer binary) throws ClassNotFoundException, SerializerException {
    return object.equals(read(binary));
  }

}
```